# How to add a checkbox for contact page in drupal?

Tags: users, emails

I added a checkbox in my register form in drupal name
**"do you want a contact form?"**

If the user checked it then in profile page a menu for contact is shown but if it says no then in the same page **"Contact:Not Reachable "** is shown.

Comment: I don't understand what you want to ask? You said you added a checkbox then what are you asking?

Comment: I added a checkbox in registration page and now I want to show the contact page based on the value of this checkbox, If it say yes, then contact page is shown else "Contact:Not Reachable"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this with Drupal core `Contact` module and with small custom code. As Drupal 7 contact module provide personal contact form and site wide contact form. See here [Working with the Contact Form](https://www.drupal.org/documentation/modules/contact). **You can enable Personal contact form by default for each user and hide the `Contact Settings` under `/user/[uid]/edit` which will be enabled for all users. Then with custom code you can show and hide Contact form Based on the Checkbox you added.**

The setting shown in below screenshot will be enabled for all users by default then you will hide this setting with custom code. Because there is no configuration to show this setting on user registration form.

[image]

Steps:

1. Enable Drupal core `Contact` module.
2. Then Goto `admin/config/people/accounts` and enable `Enable the personal contact form by default for new users.` setting.
   [image]
3. Give the following permission to Authenticated Users

   1. View user profiles
   2. Use users' personal contact forms
4. Add the checkbox field in User profile and enable that on registration form. Assuming the field name is `field_do_you_want_contact_form`.
5. Then in custom module with `hook_form_alter` hide the **personal contact form setting** and show/hide the contact form based on the value of checkbox.

   ```
   //custom.module    
   function custom_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id){

     // Hide the personal contact form setting under /user/[uid]/edit

     if ($form_id == 'user_profile_form') {
      $form['contact']['#access'] = FALSE;
     }

    // Show the Contact form Or custom message under contact tab based on checkbox value.
     if ($form_id == 'contact_personal_form') {
       $user = $form['recipient']['#value'];
       $wrapper = entity_metadata_wrapper('user', $user);
       $do_you_want_contact_form = $wrapper->field_do_you_want_contact_form->value();

       if (!$do_you_want_contact_form) {
       // hide all the contact form element.
           $form['name']['#access'] = FALSE;
           $form['mail']['#access'] = FALSE;
           $form['to']['#access'] = FALSE;
           $form['subject']['#access'] = FALSE;
           $form['message']['#access'] = FALSE;
           $form['copy']['#access'] = FALSE;
           $form['actions']['#access'] = FALSE;

       // Add custom message
           $form['not_rechable']['#markup'] = t('Contact: not rechable');
       }
     }
   }
   ```

Comment: Hello sir, Thank you for reply, as I am a novice in drupal I made a custom module and name="custom"
description="hide contact form"
core="7.x"
version="7.x-1.0"
dependencies[]="Contact"
in custom.info and this code
your code with a little change in field, but it is showing  Fatal error: __clone method called on non-object this error. Please reply

Comment: Thank you its work, There was some problem in my modules.

Comment: I am just a starter on this site, so I dont have any reputation.